# BizTalk common schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

As per best practice I have separated my BizTalk solution into projects based on artifacts (schema, pipelines, maps etc).  I've also separated business processes into solution folders.  I have created a common project to hold schema that need to be available for each and referenced these when needed... so far so good.

When I deploy it will deploy the  common schema and each reference - resulting in multiple schemas.  If I try to untick the dependency in the project assembly I get the error

> This dependency was added by the project and cannot be removed.

Am I missing something?

Visual Studio 2012, BizTalk Server Dev Ed 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Really, same answer as in the other post.

Consider the Visual Studio Solution as one Deployment Unit and build your processes around that.  Meaning, all the Projects, Schemas, Maps, Orchestrations, would always go out together even if only one changed.

I try really hard to not share Schemas across Solutions specifically because of the Deployment issues.  I do this even if it means duplicate or essentially duplicate Schemas.  99% of the time, the only thing that breaks is the automatic Schema resolution in the Xml Disassembler and that is easily solvable.

**"When I deploy it will deploy the common schema and each reference - resulting in multiple schema"**

Sorry, this part doesn't seem right.  If you have a common Schema project, there shouldn't be duplicates.

Comment: To be clear in my mind, you can deploy duplicate schema in different solutions, e.g. the Microsoft serialization, without any impact? But the Microsoft Operations Guide recommends putting common artifacts into a common solution and referencing from the different solutions.